# jQuery directly at onclick="" and effect UI slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

How can i make jQuery in a link for *onclick=""*

I need for example something like this

```
<a onclick="jQuery:$('this').hide('slow')" href="#">Close</a>
```

I know how it is this to do with classic JavaScript, but i need this with jquery for effect **slow**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the event separate from the `<a>` tag. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.close").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide("slow");
    });
});
```

with this HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rp3PZ/

If these elements are dynamically added, you can use event delegation like so:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.close", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide("slow");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zvTer/

Instead of using `document`, you should probably want to use a closer, static container element. In that case, you'd need to use `$(document).ready` like the above, as well.

---

Per the comments, this close anchor seems to be nested in a container with a class "contentbox". To hide this container when the anchor is clicked, you can use `$(this).closest(".contentbox").hide("slow");`. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rp3PZ/1/

Comment: I know ths solution, i can't do it because i hove more boxes, but i can't give dynamic id...

Comment: @MirkoSimic Where does my solution use a "dynamic id"? Give them all a common class and target it like I have it

Comment: I have now understand, but i forgott to say, can i close the outer div tag? i have tried so ´$('.contentbox').hide("slow");´, but this close all boxes...

Comment: @MirkoSimic You'd have to show your actual HTML, but I think you'd want to use `$(this).closest(".contentbox").hide("slow");`

Comment: That works perfectly... i can say only, respect and thanke you!

Comment: @MirkoSimic No problem at all! I updated my answer with a minor explanation and an example!

Answer (score 0):

Using the inline event, do this:

`<a onclick="$(this).hide('slow');return false;" href="#">Close</a>`

You had single quotes around `this` which shouldn't be there.

http://jsfiddle.net/znAWq/

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<a onclick="$(this).hide('slow')" href="#">Close</a>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/URKbM/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice not to have inline javascript in your elements. Try adding a hook to your anchor element like a class or an id.

Document Ready:

```
$(function()
{
   $(selector).click(function()
   {
        var $this = $('this');
        $this.hide('slow');
        return false;
   });
});
```